# UINavigationController in UIViewController programmatically within class

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to add a navigation controller to my `UIViewController` subclass programmatically (I'm not using storyboards) and I wanted to find the best place to init it and configure such.

I have tried `viewDidLoad` (the views weren't initialized by `init`) and a convenience `init` (just to make sure) method but no luck.

Here's how I'm creating it:

```
  override init!(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
  }
```

What would be the most appropriate method to place this logic in? I would like to keep this logic contained within this VC.

*I am able to accomplish this by creating the nav. with a root vc from the presenting VC, but this leaks this logic and I'd rather not do that.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but you could put some logic within a method in the controller you're presenting to determine whether it should be presented with or without a navigation controller; doing it this way means the presenting view controller doesn't need to know whether the controller it's presenting is embedded in a navigation controller or not. The presenting controller, would call this method after instantiating your controller. The presented controller could look something like this,

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {

    var wantsNavigationcontroller = true


    func viewControllerWithOrWithoutNavigationController() -> UIViewController {
        if wantsNavigationcontroller {
            let nav =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
            return nav
        }else{
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

The presenting controller would do this,

```
@IBAction func PresentNextcontroller(sender: UIButton) {
        var nextVC = NextViewController()
        self.presentViewController(nextVC.viewControllerWithOrWithoutNavigationController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```